# Collapsible snippet plugin not available in ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin, drupal-10

I am upgrading ckeditor4 to ckeditor5. In ckeditor4 i have used collapsible snippet plugin which is not available in ckeditor5.Should i create custom plugin in ckeditor5.

I am new to ckeditor so please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.